# From a $2-$connected graph any edge can be removed or contracted still being $2-$connected

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $G$ be a $2-$connected graph but not a triangle, and let $e$ be an edge of $G$.
>   Show that either $G − e$ or $G/e$ is again $2-$connected.

I found an answer [here](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~ugur/teaching/cs570/assignment/hw2sol.pdf). In general I don't have problems with the proof (I think it lacks a case when we suppose $x,y$ are in $P_1$ but $xy$ is not, but even in that case it can be easily solved removing the cycle which forms, however I may be mistaken and that case might not be possible for other reason).

The only problem I find is when they say

> Otherwise (If $G-e$ is not connected) $x$ and $y$ must be connected by only one path $P_{xy}$ in $G − e$.

I don't know why is that. Couldn't there be two non-independent paths between $x$ and $y$? I think I may be missing some step here. My question is what is it that I'm missing here?

Comment: They mean only one internally vertex disjoint path from $x$ to $y$.

Comment: Ok. That's it then.